# Symfony2: Datetime format based on locale

Tags: symfony, datetime-format

I have an internationalized (English/Spanish) application and I have some problems with dates. 
My date fields in forms:

```
 $builder->add('begin_date', 'date', array('required' => false, 'widget' => 'single_text'))
```

Date format by default based on locale: 
'es' => 23/05/2012
'en' => May 23, 2012

But I can't do this when locale='es' in my controller:

```
$my_datetime = new \DateTime($request->get('begin_date')
```

I have a datetime constructor error because date passed has format dd/MM/YY and should be MM/dd/YY

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Only the end to the user (so the html) is internationalized.

The data input should get mapped to a DateTime object which you should request from the form:

$form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());
$myDateTime = $form->get('BeginDate');

Comment: But in a form that is not associated with an entity. Can I do $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());? I'm talking, for example, about a  litle form filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).
Would result in something like below:

```
$formats    = array('en' => 'F d, Y', 'es' => 'd/m/Y');
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($formats[$request->getLocale()], $request->get('begin_date'));
```